# gitlab group projects in folders

Tags: gitlab

I`m a teacher and my students present their homework projects on gitlab. You can imagine that I'm now a member of hundreds of projects.
What I would like to do is to group these project under a directory structure. But I don't see anything like that on gitlab.
I'm not the owner of these projects,so I can't put them in a group.
I would like to be able to sort them by year, or by class
Any idea on how I could do that ?

Comment: By the way, you might collect downvotes on this question since it is opinion-based: there are multiple "right" answers based on how each individual person thinks it should be solved. See the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Help page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this is to create a new Group for your class itself (not year-specific), then create Sub Groups for each year/semester where your students' projects would live. The structure might look something like this:

```
Topic 101 # Group
        |
        2020 Fall # Sub Group
                |
                Alice # Project
                Bob # Project
        |
        2021 Spring # Sub Group
                  |
                  Lauren # Project
                  Daniel # Project
```

Once you create the Group+Sub Group structure, you can ask your students to Transfer their project to the right Sub Group (Project Settings->Advanced->Transfer Project).

For the next year/semester you can create the next Sub Group and create all the Projects for your students, then invite each student to their own project as Maintainers so everything is set up correctly from the beginning.

Take a look at [this project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/ci-cd/codequality) as an example. Here, the `codequality` project is in the `Ops Sub-Department` Sub Group, in the `Gitlab.Org` Group.